# Icewesel misbehave on local symbolic link to html file

Tags: html, hyperlink

Hi all I download the Gtk3.0 documentation to my hard drive and deploy it on /doc on my linux  root file system. And I've created a symbolic link to the /doc/index.html but when it navigate to other pages it uses the symbolic address as the relative path.

for a example I have symbolic link to /doc/index.html at /root/Desktop like this
    ln -S gtk_docs.html /doc/index.html

The index.html page loads fine. But lcewesel uses command line parameter as the URL, so it does not symbolically expanded. The correct behavior should be expand the symbolic link first and then load the original location into the URL if it's a symbolic link.

Any fix up or workaround for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

try to make a symbolic link of the whole folder